# Jquery .ajax() Good or Bad?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Was it somehow bad to use ajax in developing a website? I heard several rumors that it has slow response by doing ajax method. 
Any opinion or suggestion on this?

Comment: Slow in comparison to what? Do you have any alternative?

Comment: I heard several rumors that the Internet has slow response.

Comment: lets say if I have a submitting ajax or loading content ajax

Answer (score 1):

Well, AJAX certainly isn't going to reply instantly - web requests are not synchronous with the script. But I'm sure that using jQuery's AJAX wrapper functions do not slow down. Of course, you can do speed tests between the natural XMLHTTPRequest & jQuery to be sure, but I doubt there is much of, if any, a difference in response time.